# Композиция в Mongodb

Tags: база-данных, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Возник такой вопрос при написании веб-приложения, я использую mongodb в качестве базы данных, мне надо реализовать:
две сущности, User и Question, связанные композицией (при удалении User из базы данных должны удаляться все связанные с ним сущности Question), как мне это реализовать на уровне базы данных? Как её смоделировать таким образом, чтобы при ОДНОМ запросе удаления User с сервера удалились и все Question'ы?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Middleware в помощь: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post

Answer (score 0):

К приведенной ссылке добавлю небольшой пример. Оригинальный [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464861/pre-and-post-remove-middleware-not-firing).

// То есть в функцию удаления мы добавляем отдельный вызов

```
module.exports.removeUser = function(id, callback){

    User.findById(id, function (err, doc) {
        if (err) {

        }

        doc.remove(callback);
    })
}
```

//а тут уже удаляем все доки, которые относятся к этому пользователю

```
userSchema.pre('remove', function(next) {
    this.model('Voucher').remove({ user: this._id }, next);
});
```